# Fast transliteration for Arabic Text with Python

Tags: python, arabic

I always work on Arabic text files and to avoid problems with encoding I transliterate Arabic characters into English according to Buckwalter's scheme (http://www.qamus.org/transliteration.htm)

Here is my code to do so but it's very SLOW even with small files like 400 kb. Ideas to make it faster?

Thanks

```
     def transliterate(file):
          data = open(file).read()
          buckArab = {"'":"ء", "|":"آ", "?":"أ", "&":"ؤ", "<":"إ", "}":"ئ", "A":"ا", "b":"ب", "p":"ة", "t":"ت", "v":"ث", "g":"ج", "H":"ح", "x":"خ", "d":"د", "*":"ذ", "r":"ر", "z":"ز", "s":"س", "$":"ش", "S":"ص", "D":"ض", "T":"ط", "Z":"ظ", "E":"ع", "G":"غ", "_":"ـ", "f":"ف", "q":"ق", "k":"ك", "l":"ل", "m":"م", "n":"ن", "h":"ه", "w":"و", "Y":"ى", "y":"ي", "F":"ً", "N":"ٌ", "K":"ٍ", "~":"ّ", "o":"ْ", "u":"ُ", "a":"َ", "i":"ِ"}    
          for char in data: 
               for k, v in arabBuck.iteritems():
                     data = data.replace(k,v)                 
      return data
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit Oct 2021**

There was a python package recently released that does this (and a lot more), so anyone reading this post now should ignore all the other answers and just use Camel Tools. (Nizar Habash and his team at NYU Abu Dhabi are awesome for developing this and making it so accessible!)

```
::python
from camel_tools.utils.charmap import CharMapper
sentence = "ذهبت إلى المكتبة."
print(sentence)

ar2bw = CharMapper.builtin_mapper('ar2bw')

sent_bw = ar2bw(sentence)
print(sent_bw)
```

Output:

```
هبت إلى المكتبة.
*hbt <lY Almktbp.
```

You can find install instructions and tutorials here: https://github.com/CAMeL-Lab/camel_tools

---

**Old answer**
Incidentally, someone already wrote a script that does this, so you might want to check that out before spending too much time on your own:
[buckwalter2unicode.py](http://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-extras-commits/2007-June/msg03617.html)

It probably does more than what you need, but you don't have to use all of it: I copied just the two dictionaries and the transliterateString function (with a few tweaks, I think), and use that on my site.

**Edit:**
The script above is what I have been using, but I'm just discovered that it is *much* slower than using replace, especially for a large corpus.  This is the code I finally ended up with, that seems to be simpler and faster (this references a dictionary buck2uni):

```
def transString(string, reverse=0):
    '''Given a Unicode string, transliterate into Buckwalter. To go from
    Buckwalter back to Unicode, set reverse=1'''

    for k, v in buck2uni.items():
        if not reverse:
            string = string.replace(v, k)
        else:
            string = string.replace(k, v)

    return string
```

Comment: is there any dictionary for Urdu language ?

Comment: @ShanKhan — Not that I know of (not that I would know), but you can take the script above, and just modify the dictionary to work with Urdu. You just need to look up the Unicode codes for all the letters. Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

Whenever you have to do transliteration `str.translate` is the method to use:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> buckArab = {"'":"ء", "|":"آ", "?":"أ", "&":"ؤ", "<":"إ", "}":"ئ", "A":"ا", "b":"ب", "p":"ة", "t":"ت", "v":"ث", "g":"ج", "H":"ح", "x":"خ", "d":"د", "*":"ذ", "r":"ر", "z":"ز", "s":"س", "$":"ش", "S":"ص", "D":"ض", "T":"ط", "Z":"ظ", "E":"ع", "G":"غ", "_":"ـ", "f":"ف", "q":"ق", "k":"ك", "l":"ل", "m":"م", "n":"ن", "h":"ه", "w":"و", "Y":"ى", "y":"ي", "F":"ً", "N":"ٌ", "K":"ٍ", "~":"ّ", "o":"ْ", "u":"ُ", "a":"َ", "i":"ِ"}
>>> def repl(data, table):
...     for k,v in table.iteritems():
...         data = data.replace(k, v)
... 
>>> def trans(data, table):
...     return data.translate(table)
... 
>>> T = u'This is a test to see how fast is translitteration'
>>> timeit.timeit('trans(T, buckArab)', 'from __main__ import trans, T, buckArab', number=10**6)
6.766200065612793
>>> T = 'This is a test to see how fast is translitteration' #in python2 requires ASCII string
>>> timeit.timeit('repl(T, buckArab)', 'from __main__ import repl, T, buckArab', number=10**6)
12.668706893920898
```

As you can see even for small strings `str.translate` is 2 times faster.

Comment: buck = u"'|>&<}AbptvjHxd*rzs$SDTZEg_fqklmnhwYyFNKaui~o"
arabic = u"ءآأؤإئابةتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغـفقكلمنهوىيًٍََُِّْ"
tranT = maketrans(arabic, buck)          

my code stops are the 3rd line with the error message:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-44: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: I think that the problem is that `string.maketrans` works only for ASCII strings while you want to do that for unicodes. You already have a dictionary that maps arabic to english, why don't you use that as I did?

Comment: is there any dictionary like this for urdu language?

Answer (score 5):

Whenever I use `str.translate` on unicode objects it returns the same exact object. Perhaps this is due to [the change in behavior alluded to by Martijn Peters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038891/what-does-table-the-string-translate-function-mean#21038990).

If anyone else out there is struggling to transliterate unicode such as arabic to ascii, I've found that mapping ordinals to unicode literals works well.

```
>>> buckArab = {"'":"ء", "|":"آ", "?":"أ", "&":"ؤ", "<":"إ", "}":"ئ", "A":"ا", "b":"ب", "p":"ة", "t":"ت", "v":"ث", "g":"ج", "H":"ح", "x":"خ", "d":"د", "*":"ذ", "r":"ر", "z":"ز", "s":"س", "$":"ش", "S":"ص", "D":"ض", "T":"ط", "Z":"ظ", "E":"ع", "G":"غ", "_":"ـ", "f":"ف", "q":"ق", "k":"ك", "l":"ل", "m":"م", "n":"ن", "h":"ه", "w":"و", "Y":"ى", "y":"ي", "F":"ً", "N":"ٌ", "K":"ٍ", "~":"ّ", "o":"ْ", "u":"ُ", "a":"َ", "i":"ِ"}
>>> ordbuckArab = {ord(v.decode('utf8')): unicode(k) for (k, v) in buckArab.iteritems()}
>>> ordbuckArab
{1569: u"'", 1570: u'|', 1571: u'?', 1572: u'&', 1573: u'<', 1574: u'}', 1575: u'A', 1576: u'b', 1577: u'p', 1578: u't', 1579: u'v', 1580: u'g', 1581: u'H', 1582: u'x', 1583: u'd', 1584: u'*', 1585: u'r', 1586: u'z', 1587: u's', 1588: u'$', 1589: u'S', 1590: u'D', 1591: u'T', 1592: u'Z', 1593: u'E', 1594: u'G', 1600: u'_', 1601: u'f', 1602: u'q', 1603: u'k', 1604: u'l', 1605: u'm', 1606: u'n', 1607: u'h', 1608: u'w', 1609: u'Y', 1610: u'y', 1611: u'F', 1612: u'N', 1613: u'K', 1614: u'a', 1615: u'u', 1616: u'i', 1617: u'~', 1618: u'o'}
>>> u'طعصط'.translate(ordbuckArab)
u'TEST'
```

Comment: Saved me a lot of time. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Extending @larapsodia's answer, here is the complete code with dictionary:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Arabic Transliteration based on Buckwalter
# dictionary source is buckwalter2unicode.py http://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-extras-commits/2007-June/msg03617.html 

buck2uni = {"'": u"\u0621", # hamza-on-the-line
            "|": u"\u0622", # madda
            ">": u"\u0623", # hamza-on-'alif
            "&": u"\u0624", # hamza-on-waaw
            "<": u"\u0625", # hamza-under-'alif
            "}": u"\u0626", # hamza-on-yaa'
            "A": u"\u0627", # bare 'alif
            "b": u"\u0628", # baa'
            "p": u"\u0629", # taa' marbuuTa
            "t": u"\u062A", # taa'
            "v": u"\u062B", # thaa'
            "j": u"\u062C", # jiim
            "H": u"\u062D", # Haa'
            "x": u"\u062E", # khaa'
            "d": u"\u062F", # daal
            "*": u"\u0630", # dhaal
            "r": u"\u0631", # raa'
            "z": u"\u0632", # zaay
            "s": u"\u0633", # siin
            "$": u"\u0634", # shiin
            "S": u"\u0635", # Saad
            "D": u"\u0636", # Daad
            "T": u"\u0637", # Taa'
            "Z": u"\u0638", # Zaa' (DHaa')
            "E": u"\u0639", # cayn
            "g": u"\u063A", # ghayn
            "_": u"\u0640", # taTwiil
            "f": u"\u0641", # faa'
            "q": u"\u0642", # qaaf
            "k": u"\u0643", # kaaf
            "l": u"\u0644", # laam
            "m": u"\u0645", # miim
            "n": u"\u0646", # nuun
            "h": u"\u0647", # haa'
            "w": u"\u0648", # waaw
            "Y": u"\u0649", # 'alif maqSuura
            "y": u"\u064A", # yaa'
            "F": u"\u064B", # fatHatayn
            "N": u"\u064C", # Dammatayn
            "K": u"\u064D", # kasratayn
            "a": u"\u064E", # fatHa
            "u": u"\u064F", # Damma
            "i": u"\u0650", # kasra
            "~": u"\u0651", # shaddah
            "o": u"\u0652", # sukuun
            "`": u"\u0670", # dagger 'alif
            "{": u"\u0671", # waSla
}

def transString(string, reverse=0):
    '''Given a Unicode string, transliterate into Buckwalter. To go from
    Buckwalter back to Unicode, set reverse=1'''

    for k, v in buck2uni.items():
      if not reverse:
            string = string.replace(v, k)
      else:
            string = string.replace(k, v)

    return string


>>> print(transString(u'مرحبا'))
mrHbA
>>> print(transString('mrHbA', 1))
مرحبا
>>>
```

This taken from http://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-extras-commits/2007-June/msg03617.html which is licensed under the GPLv2 or later.

Comment: can you please provide some reference regarding dictionary for urdu language

Comment: I needed `>>> print(transString(variable.decode('utf8')))`

Comment: @Flimm the exact link you provided is already at the top of the code snippet :)

Comment: @AzizAlto True, but not the licensing information, which is was the real purpose of my edit. :)

Answer (score 3):

You're redoing the same work for every character.  When you do `data = data.replace(k, v)`, that replaces *all* occurrences of the given character in the entire file.  But you do this over and over in a loop, when you only need to do it once for each transliteration pair.  Just remove your outermost loop and it should speed your code up immensely.

If you need to optimize it more you could look at the string [translate method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).  I'm not sure how that is performance-wise.