# What does "table" in the string.translate function mean?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Going through the [`string.translate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) function which says:

> Delete all characters from s that are in deletechars (if present), and then translate the characters using table, which must be a 256-character string giving the translation for each character value, indexed by its ordinal. If table is None, then only the character deletion step is performed.

- What does *table* mean here? Can it be a `dict` containing the mapping?
- What does *"must be a 256-character string"* mean?
- Can the *table* be made manually or through a custom function instead of `string.maketrans`?

I tried using the function (attempts below) just to see how it worked but wasn't successfully able to use it.

```
>>> "abcabc".translate("abcabc",{ord("a"): "d", ord("c"): "x"})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: translation table must be 256 characters long
```

```
>>> "abcabc".translate({ord("a"): ord("d"), ord("c"): ord("x")}, "b")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

```
>>> "abc".translate({"a": "d", "c": "x"}, ["b"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 24):

It depends on Python version you are using.

In Python 2.x. The table is 256-characters string. It can be created using [`string.maketrans`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans):

```
>>> import string
>>> tbl = string.maketrans('ac', 'dx')
>>> "abcabc".translate(tbl)
'dbxdbx'
```

In Python 3.x, the table is mapping of unicode ordinals to unicode characters.

```
>>> "abcabc".translate({ord('a'): 'd', ord('c'): 'x'})
'dbxdbx'
```

Comment: Python 2 `unicode.translate()` behaves exactly like `str.translate()` in Python 3. That's because you have way more than 256 possible values to translate. Inversely, `bytes.translate()` works exactly like Python 2 `str.translate()`. So it does not depend on the Python version, it depends on the object type; Unicode vs bytestring.

Answer (score 10):

`table` must be a string of 256 characters; the `str.translate()` method uses this table to map the byte value (a number between 0 and 255) to a new character; e.g. any character `'a'` (a byte with the integer value 97) is replaced with the 98th character in the table.

You really want to refer to the [`str.translate()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) for all this, not the `string.translate()` function; the latter documentation is not as complete.

You can build one using [`string.maketrans`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans) function; you give it *just* the characters you want to replace with the characters that replace these; for your example, that's:

```
>>> import string
>>> table = string.maketrans('ac', 'cx')
>>> len(table)
256
>>> table[97]
'c'
>>> 'abcabc'.translate(table, 'b')
'cxcx'
```

The second argument is also supposed to be a string.

You appear to have read the documentation for the *`unicode.translate()`* method; behaviour changed and you indeed have to pass in a dictionary for `unicode.translate()`. Since the Python 2 `unicode` type is the `str` type in Python 3, that's also how you'd use `str.translate()` in Python 3 (where `bytes.translate()` matches the above behaviour).

Answer (score 0):

To translate text, not using a dictionary {ordinal: char}, but a dictionary  {char: char} (e.g. {'a': 'X', 'J': 'y', ...}:

```
text.translate({ord(k):dictionary[k] for k in dictionary})
```