# DNA to RNA using str.translate()

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I'm trying to convert the DNA code into RNA code using Python...

I write this:

```
print('Digite a sequência DNA a ser transcrita para RNA:')

my_str = raw_input()
print(my_str.replace('T', 'U'))
```

And it works, but.. now I need to convert **A to U**, **T to A**, **G to C** and **C to G**... I looked how I could do it, and did this:

```
print('Digite a sequência DNA a ser transcrita para RNA:')

my_str = raw_input()


RNA_compliment = {
    ord('A'): 'U', ord('T'): 'A',
    ord('G'): 'C', ord('C'): 'G'}

my_str.translate(RNA_compliment)
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rna2.py", line 15, in <module>
    my_str.translate(RNA_compliment)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

What i did wrong?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038891/what-does-table-the-string-translate-function-mean

Comment: [How to convert a set of DNA sequences into protein sequences using python programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40834338) has an answer of interest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### python 3:

- [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) is a static method, which returns a translation table usable for [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).
- If there are two arguments, they must be strings of equal length.

```py
i, j = "ATGC", "UACG"

tbl = str.maketrans(i, j)

my_str = "GUTC"

print(my_str.translate(tbl))

[out]:
'CUAG'
```

#### Using `RNA_compliment`

- `str.maketrans` accepts one argument as a dictionary
- `{ord('A'): 'U', ord('T'): 'A', ord('G'): 'C', ord('C'): 'G'}`

  - `ord()` isn't required

```py
# dict without ord
RNA_compliment = {'A': 'U', 'T': 'A', 'G': 'C', 'C': 'G'}

tbl2 = i.maketrans(RNA_compliment)

print(my_str.translate(tbl2))

[out]:
'CUAG'
```

### python 2:

- If you want to make a table, use [`string.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans).
- You can only use the `ord` with a `dict` for *python3*, **not** for *python2*:

```py
In [1]: from string import maketrans

In [2]: i, j = "ATGC", "UACG"

In [3]: tbl = maketrans(i,j)

In [4]: my_str = "GUTC"

In [5]:  my_str.translate(tbl)
Out[5]: 'CUAG'
```