# How to split a string into equal sized parts?

Tags: python, string, bioinformatics

I have a string that contains a sequence of nucleotides. The string is 1191 nucleotides long.

How do I print the sequence in a format which each line only has 100 nucleotides? right now I have it hard coded but I would like it to work for any string of nucleotides. here is the code I have now

```
def printinfasta(SeqName, Sequence, SeqDescription):
    print(SeqName + " " + SeqDescription)
    #how do I make sure to only have 100 nucleotides per line?
    print(Sequence[0:100])
    print(Sequence[100:200])
    print(Sequence[200:300])
    print(Sequence[400:500])
    print(Sequence[500:600])
    print(Sequence[600:700])
    print(Sequence[700:800])
    print(Sequence[800:900])
    print(Sequence[900:1000])
    print(Sequence[1000:1100])
    print(Sequence[1100:1191])
printinfasta(SeqName, Sequence, SeqDescription)
```

```py
Sequence = "NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAATCCATAAATCCCTAAAACCATAATCCTAAATCCCTTAATTCCTAAATCCCTAATACTTAGACCCTAATCTTTAGTTCCTAGACCCTAATCTTTAGTTCCTAGACCCTAAATCCATAATCCTTAATTCCTAAATTCCTAAATCCCTAATACTAAATCTCTAAATCCCTAGCAATTTTCAAGTTTTGCTTGATTGTTGTAGGATGGTCCTTTCTCTTGTTTCTTCTCTGTGTTGTTGAGATTAGTTTGTTTAGGTTTGATAGCGTTGATTTTGGCCTGCGTTTGGTGACTCATATGGTTTGATTGGAGTTTGTTTCTGGGTTTTATGGTTTTGGTTGAAGCGACATTTTTTTGTGGAATATGGTTTTTGCAAAATATTTTGTTCCGGATGAGTAATATCTACGGTGCTGCTGTGAGAATTATGCTATTGTTTT"
```

Comment: Here is an answer of interest [DNA to RNA using str.translate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32018654)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a string to even sized chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351275/split-a-string-to-even-sized-chunks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `textwrap.wrap` to split long strings into list of strings

```
import textwrap

seq = "NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAATCCATAAATCCCTAAAACCATAATCCTAAATCCCTTAATTCCTAAATCCCTAATACTTAGACCCTAATCTTTAGTTCCTAGACCCTAATCTTTAGTTCCTAGACCCTAAATCCATAATCCTTAATTCCTAAATTCCTAAATCCCTAATACTAAATCTCTAAATCCCTAGCAATTTTCAAGTTTTGCTTGATTGTTGTAGGATGGTCCTTTCTCTTGTTTCTTCTCTGTGTTGTTGAGATTAGTTTGTTTAGGTTTGATAGCGTTGATTTTGGCCTGCGTTTGGTGACTCATATGGTTTGATTGGAGTTTGTTTCTGGGTTTTATGGTTTTGGTTGAAGCGACATTTTTTTGTGGAATATGGTTTTTGCAAAATATTTTGTTCCGGATGAGTAATATCTACGGTGCTGCTGTGAGAATTATGCTATTGTTTT"
print('\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(seq, width=100)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest` and some `iter` magic to get this in one line:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

sequence = "NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAATCCATAAATCCCTAAAACCATAATCCTAAATCCCTTAATTCCTAAATCCCTAATACTTAGACCCTAATCTTTAGTTCCTAGACCCTAATCTTTAGTTCCTAGACCCTAAATCCATAATCCTTAATTCCTAAATTCCTAAATCCCTAATACTAAATCTCTAAATCCCTAGCAATTTTCAAGTTTTGCTTGATTGTTGTAGGATGGTCCTTTCTCTTGTTTCTTCTCTGTGTTGTTGAGATTAGTTTGTTTAGGTTTGATAGCGTTGATTTTGGCCTGCGTTTGGTGACTCATATGGTTTGATTGGAGTTTGTTTCTGGGTTTTATGGTTTTGGTTGAAGCGACATTTTTTTGTGGAATATGGTTTTTGCAAAATATTTTGTTCCGGATGAGTAATATCTACGGTGCTGCTGTGAGAATTATGCTATTGTTTT" 

output = [''.join(filter(None, s)) for s in zip_longest(*([iter(sequence)]*100))]
```

Or:

```
for s in zip_longest(*([iter(sequence)]*100)):
    print(''.join(filter(None, s)))
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to use `re` module.

```
import re

def splitstring(strg, leng):
    chunks = re.findall('.{1,%d}' % leng, strg)
    for i in chunks:
        print(i)


splitstring(strg = seq, leng = 100))
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your sequence is in FASTA format. If this is the case, you can use any of a number of bioinformatics packages that provide FASTA sequence wrapping utilities. For example, you can use [`FASTX-Toolkit`](http://hannonlab.cshl.edu/fastx_toolkit/). Wrap FASTA sequences using [`FASTA Formatter`](http://hannonlab.cshl.edu/fastx_toolkit/commandline.html#fasta_formatter_usage) command line utility, for example to a max of 100 nucleotides per line:

```
fasta_formatter -i INFILE -o OUTFILE -w 100
```

You can install `FASTX-Toolkit` package using `conda`, for example:
`conda install fastx_toolkit`
or
`conda create -n fastx_toolkit fastx_toolkit`

Note that if you end up writing the (simple) code to wrap FASTA sequences from scratch, remember that the header lines (the lines starting with `>`) should *not* be wrapped. Wrap only the sequence lines.

**SEE ALSO:**

[Convert single line fasta to multi line fasta](https://www.biostars.org/p/205745/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a helper function based on [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest). The helper function has been designed to (also) handle cases where the sequence isn't an exact multiple of the size of the equal parts (the last group will have fewer elements than those before it).

```
from itertools import zip_longest


def grouper(n, iterable):
    """ s -> (s0,s1,...sn-1), (sn,sn+1,...s2n-1), (s2n,s2n+1,...s3n-1), ... """
    FILLER = object()  # Value that couldn't be in data.
    for result in zip_longest(*[iter(iterable)]*n, fillvalue=FILLER):
        yield ''.join(v for v in result if v is not FILLER)


def printinfasta(SeqName, Sequence, SeqDescription):
    print(SeqName + " " + SeqDescription)
    for group in grouper(100, Sequence):
        print(group)

Sequence = "NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAATCCATAAATCCCTAAAACCATAATCCTAAATCCCTTAATTCCTAAATCCCTAATACTTAGACCCTAATCTTTAGTTCCTAGACCCTAATCTTTAGTTCCTAGACCCTAAATCCATAATCCTTAATTCCTAAATTCCTAAATCCCTAATACTAAATCTCTAAATCCCTAGCAATTTTCAAGTTTTGCTTGATTGTTGTAGGATGGTCCTTTCTCTTGTTTCTTCTCTGTGTTGTTGAGATTAGTTTGTTTAGGTTTGATAGCGTTGATTTTGGCCTGCGTTTGGTGACTCATATGGTTTGATTGGAGTTTGTTTCTGGGTTTTATGGTTTTGGTTGAAGCGACATTTTTTTGTGGAATATGGTTTTTGCAAAATATTTTGTTCCGGATGAGTAATATCTACGGTGCTGCTGTGAGAATTATGCTATTGTTTT"

printinfasta('Name', Sequence, 'Description')
```

Sample output:

```
Name Description
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
CCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAATCCATAAATCCCTAAAACCATAATCCTAAATCCCTTAATTCCTA
AATCCCTAATACTTAGACCCTAATCTTTAGTTCCTAGACCCTAATCTTTAGTTCCTAGACCCTAAATCCATAATCCTTAATTCCTAAATTCCTAAATCCC
TAATACTAAATCTCTAAATCCCTAGCAATTTTCAAGTTTTGCTTGATTGTTGTAGGATGGTCCTTTCTCTTGTTTCTTCTCTGTGTTGTTGAGATTAGTT
TGTTTAGGTTTGATAGCGTTGATTTTGGCCTGCGTTTGGTGACTCATATGGTTTGATTGGAGTTTGTTTCTGGGTTTTATGGTTTTGGTTGAAGCGACAT
TTTTTTGTGGAATATGGTTTTTGCAAAATATTTTGTTCCGGATGAGTAATATCTACGGTGCTGCTGTGAGAATTATGCTATTGTTTT
```

Answer (score 0):

Package `cytoolz` (installable using `pip install cytoolz`) provides a function [`partition_all`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.partition_all) that can be used here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from cytoolz import partition_all

def printinfasta(name, seq, descr):
    header = f">{name} {descr}"
    print(header)
    print(*map("".join, partition_all(100, seq)), sep="\n")


printinfasta("test", 468 * "ACGTGA", "this is a test")
```

`partition_all(100, seq))` generate tuples of 100 letters each taken from `seq`, and a last shorter one is the number of letters is not a multiple of 100.

The `map("".join, ...)` is used to group letters within each such tuple into a single string.

The `*` in front of the `map` makes its results considered as separate arguments to `print`.