# Encoder for a string - Python

Tags: python, string, loops, dictionary, encoding

I've been playing around with encoding random sets of strings using a dictionary. I've gotten my code to replace the letters I want, but in some cases it will replace a character more than once, when I truly only want it to replace the letter in the string once. This is what I have:

```
def encode(msg,code):
    for i in msg:
        for i in code:
            msg = msg.replace(i, code[i])
        return msg
```

for testing purposes I used the function calls:
initial:

```
encode("blagh", {"a":"e","h":"r"})
```

and a more complex string:

```
encode("once upon a time",{'a':'ae','e':'ei','i':'io','o':'ou','u':'ua'})
```

for the second one right above, I'm looking for the output of : 
'ouncei uapoun ae tiomei'

but instead am finding myself with :

"ounceio uapoun aeio tiomeio"

How can I limit my loop to only replacing each character once?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038891/what-does-table-the-string-translate-function-mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3's [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translate#str.translate) function does what you want.  Note that the translation dictionary must use Unicode ordinals for keys, so the function uses a dictionary comprehension to convert it to the right format:

```
def encode(msg,code):
    code = {ord(k):v for k,v in code.items()}
    return msg.translate(code)

print(encode("blagh", {"a":"e","h":"r"}))
print(encode("once upon a time",{'a':'ae','e':'ei','i':'io','o':'ou','u':'ua'}))
```

Output:

```
blegr
ouncei uapoun ae tiomei
```

It works in Python 2 as well if you use Unicode strings or add the following to the top of the file to make strings Unicode by default:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `str.replace`, replace character by character:

```
def encode(msg, code):
    result = ''
    for ch in msg:
        result += code.get(ch, ch)
    return result
```

Using [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
def encode(msg, code):
    return ''.join(code.get(ch, ch) for ch in msg)
```