# Why is str.translate() returning an error and how can I fix it?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import os

def rename_files():
    file_list = os.listdir(r"D:\360Downloads\test")
    saved_path = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(r"D:\360Downloads\test")

    for file_name in file_list:
        os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None,"0123456789"))

rename_files()
```

the error message is `TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)`. How can I format this so that `translate()` does not return an error?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Your question should be on `str.translate`. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21038977/4831822), there are also plenty of questions out there on renaming files.

Comment: can you post some examples of strings original -> translated? I don't understand what you want to do with `translate`

Comment: I want to delete the number in filename .

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps!

```
os.rename(file_name,file_name.translate(str.maketrans('','','0123456789')))
```

or

```
os.rename(file_name,file_name.translate({ ord(i) : None for i in '0123456789' }))
```

**Explanation:**

I think you're using Python 3.x and syntax for Python 2.x. In Python 3.x [translate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) syntax is

> str.translate(table)

which takes only one argument, not like Python 2.x in which [translate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) syntax is

> str.translate(table[, deletechars])

which can takes more than one arguments.

We can make translation table easily using *maketrans* function.
In this case, In first two parameters, we're replacing *nothing* to *nothing* and in third parameter we're specifying which characters to be removed.

We can also make translation table manually using dictionary in which key contains ASCII of *before* and value contains ASCII of *after* character.If we want to remove some character it value must be None.
I.e. if we want to replace 'A' with 'a' and remove '1' in string then our dictionary looks like this

> {65: 97, 49: None}