# ValueError: translation table must be 256 characters long

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have python flask project (program) where I am converting user's input string with capital letters and punctuations into a string without them. When I run the program I getting the following error:

```
ValueError: translation table must be 256 characters long

 Traceback (most recent call last) File:

"/home/sd18656/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line
2463, in __call__ return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response) File
"/home/sd18656/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line
2449, in wsgi_app response = self.handle_exception(e) File
"/home/sd18656/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line
1866, in handle_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) File
"/home/sd18656/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line
2446, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File
"/home/sd18656/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line
1951, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) File
"/home/sd18656/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line
1820, in handle_user_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) File
"/home/sd18656/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line
1949, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File
"/home/sd18656/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line
1935, in dispatch_request return
self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args) File
"/home/sd18656/FlaskProject/mainapp.py", line 61, in home score,
total_processed_data = get_score(abstract) File
"/home/sd18656/FlaskProject/mainapp.py", line 32, in get_score
abstract = abstract.translate(string.punctuation).lower()
```

In the program, abstract is a string type. I came across this solution: [What does "table" in the string.translate function mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038891/what-does-table-in-the-string-translate-function-mean) for the error, however, the `string.maketrans` does not seem to go well with `lower()` or`upper()`. How can I fix this issue?

The code snippet which is causing this issue as follows:

```
r = reader(open('mycsv.csv','r'))
abstract_list = []
score_list = []
institute_list = []
row_count = 0
for row in list(r)[1:]:
    institute,score,abstract = row[0], row[1], row[2]
    if len(abstract.split()) > 0:
      institute_list.append(institute)
      score = float(score)
      score_list.append(score)
      abstract = abstract.translate(string.punctuation).lower()
      abstract_list.append(abstract)
      row_count = row_count + 1
```

Content of mycsv.csv is something as follows:

[image]

Comment: Please add the code that actually generates the error.

Comment: We'll also need the file 'mycsv.csv'

Comment: @chepner i have added the code snippet. Thanks.

Comment: use string.maketrans() function before translate()

Comment: @ManishGupta actually i tried using  string.maketrans(), however, even in the python doc it mentions: Don’t use strings derived from lowercase and uppercase as arguments; in some locales, these don’t have the same length. For case conversions, always use str.lower() and str.upper().

Comment: Are you trying to replace `punctuation` with space or something? If that is the case then call `abstract.translate(''.maketrans(string.punctuation, ' ' *len(string.punctuation))).lower()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a translation table to `str.translate` (`string.translate` in Python 2). The translation table is nothing more than a `dict` where the `key` is the search character and `value` is the replacement, where `key` and `value` are the `ord()` of the respective characters.

If you want to replace all `punctuation` characters with space, for example, do something like this:

```py
from string import punctuation
transtable = string.maketrans(punctuation, ' ' * len(punctuation))

abstract = abstract.translate(transtable).lower()
```

Here is a proof of concept:

```py
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> transtable = string.maketrans(punctuation, ' ' * len(punctuation))
>>> type(transtable)
<class 'dict'>
>>> 'This!is#a.string,with;punctuations:'.translate(transtable).lower()
'this is a string with punctuations '
>>>
```

Here is another usage example of `maketrans` and `translate` (just for fun):

```py
>>> elite = string.maketrans('aeiou', '4310v')
>>> 'Hackers Rulez'.translate(elite)
'H4ck3rs Rvl3z'
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually str works for python 3 but not for python 2 and throws error. Since the original answer was based on python 2, that’s why I changed it to string rather than str.

Comment: Oh! I see. I missed that Python version completely. If you don't mind, go ahead and edit it again, please.