# How to transliterate Urdu word to Roman Urdu Phonetically using Google Translator

Tags: python, google-translate, urdu

Is there any way to transliterate Urdu Word to Roman Urdu using Google Translator Phonetically ?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Urdu

I want to use Translator API in python to convert the word but unable to do so.

Comment: Read this in the mean time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757344/fast-transliteration-for-arabic-text-with-python

Comment: Thanks, i will read, Google had Transliterate API that has been deprecated, have you used that API ? will that work also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have posted the post here with code in python

https://medium.com/@itsShanKhan/transliterate-urdu-to-roman-urdu-in-python-614953b1a4d5#.bhnrsrany